# How to set headers in Angular2 by extending BrowserXhr?

Tags: angular, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I am setting header for Angular 2 app.
Here is my code:

```
 @Injectable()
    export class browserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
      constructor() {}
      build(): any {
        let xhr:XMLHttpRequest = super.build();
         xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Custom-Header', 'value');
        return <any>(xhr);
      }
    }
```

As I run it gives error

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the error you get to the question.

Comment: it gives error at --> xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Custom-Header', 'value'); says unable to set.

Answer (score 1):

Without you posting the error, it's just guess work as to what's going wrong. But probably you should add a `super()` call inside the constructor. Another point of interest is the almost same name of the class, besides the capital. It's common practice to have your class name in `PascalCase`:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class MyBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
      constructor() {
         super(); //<-- here
      }

      build(): XMLHttpRequest {
        let xhr:XMLHttpRequest = <XMLHttpRequest>super.build();
        xhr.open(method, url, async?, user?, password?); //fill in the correct details
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Custom-Header', 'value');
        return xhr;
      }
 }
```

After you posted your error, it is obvious what you have to do first. Before setting the request headers, you have to open the request using the [`open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) method:

```
xhr.open(method, url, async?, user?, password?);
```

After you call this method, you will be able to set your request headers

Comment: I applied above method but it give error i posted it on question part.